# What does "safely escaped with Go syntax" mean?

Tags: go, escaping, string-formatting

Go's [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package defines `%q` (for strings) as:

```
 %q      a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax
```

What does ***safely escaped with Go syntax*** mean?

Some experimentation shows it preserves escape sequences used in the original string:

```
s := "This has \"quotes\" in it"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)             // output: "This has \"quotes\" in it"
```

Is there anything else it does? In what situations might you want to use this? I'm guessing perhaps in templates that generate Go code?

Comment: please check the answer and please accept if it helps.

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai while I haven't downvoted this question myself, if you hover over the downvote button you'll see the "default reasoning" in the tooltip, so if the downvoter hasn't provided any more details you could, if you want to, assume the default.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the formatted output would be escaped properly that it can be copied and used in the go source code

Example formattings

```
 "abc"          => `"abc"`
 []byte("abc")  => `"abc"`
 ""             => `""`
 "\""           => `"\""`
 `\n`           => `"\\n"`
 renamedBytes([]byte("hello")) => `"hello"`
 []renamedUint8{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'} => `"hello"`
 reflect.ValueOf("hello") => `"hello"`
```

Code explaining the above

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type renamedBytes []byte
    type renamedUint8 uint8

    fmt.Printf("%q\n", "abc")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", []byte("abc"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", "\n")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", []renamedUint8{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'})
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", renamedBytes([]byte("hello")))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", reflect.ValueOf("hello"))
}
```

Comment: It was an example 'renamedBytes'  a type derived from bytes.    

type renamedBytes []bytes
and try this

Answer (score -1):

it transforms a strange / malformed input into something that is safe to use

it would change the string representation of this byte array 
[]byte{56 ,21 ,114 ,215 ,252 ,199 ,62 ,146 ,143 ,167 ,197 ,162 ,172 ,158 ,112 ,4 ,76 ,17 ,222 ,32 ,34 ,215 ,199 ,97 ,187 ,143 ,61 ,161 ,211, 96 ,198 ,218 ,134 ,106 ,85 ,107 ,162 ,194 ,36 ,153, 255}  from "o<�i���H���O��Ia)eb�?G(V���H" into "\x9d\xd8ջ\x90\xf13\x89\xd6\xd0\v2\xc0\xbe.m\xaa!B\xbf\xbe\xe7s\x0e\xff\xac\xf4Ӕ\xe6Dx\x88\xd3c\xa2P\x16n\x97\xc8"

but "hello world" would remain "hello world"

if the byte array is printer straight into your terminal it might make your terminal look weird, for example my terminal returned this " "D␊␌⎼≤⎻├␊␍ ⎽├⎼␋┼± "H␊┌┌⎺, ┬⎺⎼┌␍!", when i used string() instead of "%q"

Comment: that is because in my example is a byte array represented as a string, the byte array is []byte{56 ,21 ,114 ,215 ,252 ,199 ,62 ,146 ,143 ,167 ,197 ,162 ,172 ,158 ,112 ,4 ,76 ,17 ,222 ,32 ,34 ,215 ,199 ,97 ,187 ,143 ,61 ,161 ,211, 96 ,198 ,218 ,134 ,106 ,85 ,107 ,162 ,194 ,36 ,153, 255} i will edit it into my answer

Comment: Not necessarily "strange / malformed". It could just contain, as the question's example shows, quotes.